# How to identify substring of a cell value in an excel sheet using python openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to identify the given search_word for eg `'.pdf'` is available in the cell value for eg **'economics.pdf'** using python `openpyxl`. How can I achieve. I'm new to coding, can anyone help

I tried below code but it didn't help. I want to print the cell value if given 'search_word' is found in the cell value.

eg. Excel sheet

[image]

my code

```
def func1():

    file_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')

     sheet_obj = file_obj.active
     row=0
     for val in sheet_obj['C']:
         row=row+1
         if sheet_obj.cell(row=row,column=3).value in 'search_word':
             print("substring is available",sheet_obj.cell(row=row,column=3).value,"in the cell",val)
         else:
             print("No substring ", sheet_obj.cell(row=row,column=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you just need to make `search_word` as a parameter of your `func()`, not as a *string*.

Try this :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def func1(search_word):
    file_obj = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
    sheet_obj = file_obj.active

    for cell in sheet_obj['C']:
        if search_word in str(cell.value):
            print(f"Substring '{search_word}' is available in the cell '{cell.value}'")
        else:
            print(f"No substring '{search_word}' found in the cell '{cell.value}'")
```

Output :

```
func1('.pdf')

No substring '.pdf' found in the cell 'Economics.imgurl'
No substring '.pdf' found in the cell 'Indiatoday'
Substring '.pdf' is available in the cell 'Hindy.pdf'
No substring '.pdf' found in the cell 'Economics'
No substring '.pdf' found in the cell 'Wiki'
No substring '.pdf' found in the cell 'Hindu'
No substring '.pdf' found in the cell 'hindu.google.co'
```

Input used (*spreadsheet*) :

[image]